# WCF Configuration for Security Not Working: Throwing The request for security token has invalid or malformed elements

Tags: c#, xml, asp.net-mvc, wcf, config

I think something is wrong with my config. I am trying to get a password protected security wrapped in IIS (not achieved yet), and I am getting all sorts of exceptions. This time I am getting a security token invalid or malformed element exception. Here are my configs:

HOST:

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <wsHttpBinding>
      <binding name ="WSHttpBinding_ISVC1">
        <security mode="Message">
          <message clientCredentialType="UserName" establishSecurityContext="false"/>
        </security>
      </binding>
      </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="SVCBehaviors">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
          <serviceCredentials>
            <userNameAuthentication userNamePasswordValidationMode="Custom" customUserNamePasswordValidatorType="blahblah.SVCValidator, TrademarkGlobal.Web"/>
          </serviceCredentials>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <services>
      <service name="blahblah.SVC"
         behaviorConfiguration="SVCBehaviors">
        <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding"
   contract="blahblah.ISVC" name="WSHttpBinding_ISVC1"/>
        <endpoint contract="IMetadataExchange"
           binding="mexHttpBinding" address="mex"/>
      </service>
    </services>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>

CLIENT: 
   <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="WSHttpBinding_ISVC1">
          <security mode="Message">
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName" establishSecurityContext="false"/>
          </security>
        </binding>
      </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="http://localhost:64609/SVC.svc" binding="wsHttpBinding"
          bindingConfiguration="WSHttpBinding_ISVC1" contract="ISVC">
      </endpoint>
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

SVC FILE (svc.svc):

```
<%@ServiceHost Service="blahblah.SVC" %>
```

The Service (SVC & ISVC) just returns a basic strin g for now.

SVCVALIDATOR.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.IdentityModel.Selectors;
public class SVCValidator : UserNamePasswordValidator
{
    public override void Validate(string userName, string password)
    {
        if (userName == null || password == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        }
        if (userName != "gooduser" && password != "goodpass")
        {
            throw new Exception("Incorrect Username or Password");
        }
    }
}
```

CONTROLLER ACTION USED TO RUN:

```
   public class SVCController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index(string user = "bad", string pass = "bad")
    {
        using (SVCClient client = new SVCClient())
        {
        //SVCClient client = new SVCClient("WSHttpBinding_ISVC");
        client.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = user;
        client.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = pass;
        ViewBag.Message = client.Test();
        return View("RunningSVC");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think the error means basically that the server can't compile.  To see the real error message, go to the URL for the service *blahblah.SVC*.  What do you see there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not use Binding configuration in server.

Your configuration has a name:

```
  <bindings>
      <wsHttpBinding>
      <binding name ="WSHttpBinding_ISVC1">
        <security mode="Message">
          <message clientCredentialType="UserName" establishSecurityContext="false"/>
        </security>
      </binding>
      </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
```

But Endpoint does not refer that configuration name.
Correct endpoint should be:

```
 <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding"
   contract="blahblah.ISVC" name="WSHttpBinding_ISVC1" bindingConfiguration="WSHttpBinding_ISVC1" />
```

Please let me know if that solved the issue.

Comment: new exception: {"The requested service, 'http://localhost:64609/SVC.svc' could not be activated. See the server's diagnostic trace logs for more information."}. i assume this is a step forward.

Going forward provides this: The service certificate is not provided. Specify a service certificate in ServiceCredentials. I do not want a certificate.

Comment: You have to use certificate to protect your password. It should be either message level (your config) or transport - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733775.aspx

Comment: See also this - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pedram/archive/2007/10/05/wcf-authentication-custom-username-and-password-validator.aspx It contains working code for  <security mode="Message">